# Javascript - array index issue in non sparse array

Tags: javascript

non sparse array are contiguous in nature and from 0 to length-1, all index should return true for 'in' operator. It should be true also for empty element.

```
obj1 = {x:1,y:2};
obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.z = 5;
var arr = [obj1,obj2,1,,2];

console.log(arr.length); //5
console.log(3 in arr);//false
```

index 3 is valid.
Why is it returning false?

Note: I am using latest firefox.

It should return false only for sparse array which doesn't have a specified index number 3.

Update: index 3 is valid so it should return true. in operator doesn't validate value of at the indexed position, it just validate the validity of index not the value

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#Using_in_with_deleted_or_undefined_properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`3 in arr` is `false` because `arr[3]` is never set (and thus the array is indeed sparse).

Note the double comma in

```
var arr = [obj1,obj2,1,,2];
```

– if you make that

```
var arr = [obj1,obj2,1,2];
```

then `3 in arr` becomes `true`.

See page 63 in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> Array elements may be elided at the beginning, middle or end of the element list. Whenever a comma in the 
>   element list is not preceded by an  AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after another 
>   comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of 
>   subsequent elements. Elided array elements are not defined. If an element is elided at the end of an array, 
>   that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

– in other words, the behavior of your code is identical to

```
var arr = [obj1, obj2, 1];
arr[4] = 2;
```

Comment: isn't [obj1,obj2,1,,2] is equivalent to [obj1,obj2,1,undefined,2] ?

Comment: i think firefox doesn't follow ECMA standard, var a = [,,,]; // This array is [undefined, undefined, undefined], no need to explicitly assign value at these indexes to undefined.

Comment: Effectively `[obj1,obj2,1,,2]` gives you `{0: obj1, 1: obj2, 2: 1, 4: 2, length: 5}` with a different prototype object (and a custom [[DefineOwnProperty]] which makes "length" get set magically), which obviously has no "3" property.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is evaluating the value which is undefined. Undefined is falsy.

Array always have 0 based index, in your array 4th element (3 by index) is not set to any value.

Refere [this](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)

*From the link*

> Here is what is falsy in JavaScript:
>
> - false
> - null
> - undefined
> - The empty string
> - ''
> - The number 0 The number NaN    (yep, 'Not a Number' is a number, it is a special number)
>
> Everything else is truthy, and that includes Infinity (which is
>   another special number, like NaN), and all Object objects and Array
>   objects, empty or not.

Comment: `0 in [undefined] === true` so I'm not sure this is completely correct.

Comment: index 3 is valid so it should return true. in operator doesn't validate value of at the indexed position, it just validate the validity of index not the value.